# How to remove specific sections in a json file

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

Alright so I have a JSON file where I keep a few user ids to come back to for certain command. Now what I want to do is be able to add and remove ids with commands. I've gotten the adding all figured out but removing them I can't for the life of me

```js
else if (command === 'whitelist') { //command
var checker = whitelist; //whitelist json file
let test = Object.values(checker.users).find((value) => value.id === msg.author.id); //check id
if(!test)return msg.reply("Sorry you can't use this!");
if(test){
const user = msg.mentions.users.first();
if (!user) return msg.reply('Please mention a user!')
const json = require('./test.json') //teporary test file will be whitelist.json later
const item = Object.values(json.newdata).find(object => object.ID === user.id)
if (item){
msg.reply("Remove mentioned user from whitelist?")
msg.react(':thumbsup:').then(r => {
msg.react(':thumbsdown:');});
msg.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == msg.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == ':thumbsup:' || reaction.emoji.name == ':thumbsdown:'),
{ max: 1, time: 30000 }).then(collected => {if (collected.first().emoji.name == ':thumbsup:') {

//here idk what to add to remove a sertain section from a json

msg.reply("Removed user!")}
else
msg.reply('Operation canceled.');
}).catch(() => {msg.reply('No reaction after 30 seconds, operation canceled');});
return
}
if (!item){ 
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./test.json');
msg.reply("Add mentioned user to whitelist?")
msg.react(':thumbsup:').then(r => {
msg.react(':thumbsdown:');});
msg.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == msg.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == ':thumbsup:' || reaction.emoji.name == ':thumbsdown:'),
{ max: 1, time: 30000 }).then(collected => {if (collected.first().emoji.name == ':thumbsup:') {
let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
data.newdata [user] = {"ID": user.id}
fs.writeFile("./test.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), (err) => {
if (err) 
embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('Error report')
.addField(`Logged error:`, err, false)
.addField(`Server:`, `${msg.guild}`, false)
.addField(`Command:`, `${command} ${commandArgs}`, false)
.setColor('#0099ff');
webhookClient.send(embed)
})
msg.reply("Whitelisted user!")}
else
msg.reply('Operation canceled.');
}).catch(() => {msg.reply('No reaction after 30 seconds, operation canceled');});
return}}
}
```

above u can find the whole command
heres the Json file

```js
{
  "newdata": {
    "<@804786710264938536>": {//for example if i want to i could remove this id from the file 
      "ID": "804786710264938536"
    },
    "<@361511417800556546>": {
      "ID": "361511417800556546"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the delete operator? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

If you have the name of the property you want to delete you'd just do ```delete obj.prop```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript has a `delete` operator, so you can call the JSON with the delete operator to delete a certain section;

```js
delete data.newdata
// OR
delete data['newdata']
```

[More information on the delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: this doesnt seem to work or im just doing it wrong? is this how u would do it?
 `let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./whitelist.json');
let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
delete data.newdata

msg.reply("Removed user!")}`

Comment: @pitchedmobile Calling delete only deletes it from the data loaded into memory, after you delete it you need to write back to the json file.

Answer (score 0):

alright so all i had to do was this

```js
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./whitelist.json');
let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
delete data.newdata [user]
```